# Is it possible to create a float array of 10^13 elements in C?

Tags: c

I am writing a program in C to solve an optimisation problem, for which I need to create an array of type float with an order of 10<sup>13</sup> elements. Is it practically possible to do so on a machine with 20GB memory.

Comment: Not unless you have 40TB of memory hanging around. You might be better off describing your actual problem.

Comment: Must all this fit into RAM or are you allowed to page stuff in and out? But C itself would not prohibit you from creating such a big array. The OS on the other hand might have its problems with it.

Comment: You can't have 40TB RAM on a pc, maybe on a supercomputer.It's possible if you have enough disk space to page it, but it's probably going to make the code slower that it's without this "optimization"

Comment: @lazy_banana Work out how long it's going to take to _access_ all that memory. A linear algorithm that can fully process 1 billion items per second (fast!) will take nearly 3 hours. I'd be really surprised if any non-trivial optimization problem was linear though, or able to deliver that speed for real even on a supercomputer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `float` in C occupies 4 bytes (assuming IEEE floating point arithmetic, which is pretty close to universal nowadays). That means 10<sup>13</sup> elements are naïvely going to require  4×10<sup>13</sup> bytes of space. That's quite a bit (40 TB, a.k.a. quite a lot of disk for a desktop system, and rather more than most people can afford when it comes to RAM) so you need to find another approach.

Is the data sparse (i.e., mostly zeroes)? If it is, you can try using a hash table or tree to store only the values which are anything else; if your data is sufficiently sparse, that'll let you fit everything in. Also be aware that processing 10<sup>13</sup> elements will take a very long time. Even if you could process a billion items a second (very fast, even now) it would still take 10<sup>4</sup> seconds (several hours) and I'd be willing to bet that in any non-trivial situation you'll not be able to get anything near that speed. Can you find some way to make not just the data storage sparse but also the processing, so that you can leave that massive bulk of zeroes alone?

Of course, if the data is non-sparse then you're doomed. In that case, you might need to find a smaller, more tractable problem instead.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose if you had a 64 bit machine with a lot of swap space, you could just declare an array of size 10^13 and it may work.

But for a data set of this size it becomes important to consider carefully the nature of the problem.  Do you really need random access read and write operations for all 10^13 elements?  Is the array at all sparse?  Could you express this as a map/reduce problem?  If so, sequential access to 10^13 elements is much more practical than random access.